# insomnia on ubuntu Gtk-WARNING **: 18:49:38.190: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1413:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

Tags: 22.04, crash, javascript

I have this problem when I try to open insomnia on ubuntu and I don't want to delete it so I don't lose my work

has anyone had this problem?

> A JavaScript error occurred in the main process Uncaught
> Exception: Error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version
> `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by
> /run/user/1000/snap.insomnia/.org.chromium.Chromium.eCprA9)
> at process.func [as dlopen] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:1822)
> at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1226:18)
> at Object.func [as .node] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:2049)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1011:32)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:846:12)
> at f._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13328)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1035:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
> at Object. (/snap/insomnia/184/resources/app.asar/node_modules/@getinsomnia/node-libcurl/dist/Easy.js:5:18)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:14)
>
> (insomnia:4925): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:49:38.190: Theme parsing error:
> gtk.css:1413:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
>
> (insomnia:4925): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:49:38.197: Theme parsing error:
> gtk.css:3286:25: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
>
> (insomnia:4925): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:49:38.198: Theme parsing error:
> gtk.css:3748:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
> WARNING: Kernel has no file descriptor comparison support: Operation
> not permitted A JavaScript error occurred in the main process Uncaught
> Exception: Error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version
> `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by
> /run/user/1000/snap.insomnia/.org.chromium.Chromium.eCprA9)
> at process.func [as dlopen] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:1822)
> at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1226:18)
> at Object.func [as .node] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:2049)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1011:32)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:846:12)
> at f._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13328)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1035:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
> at Object. (/snap/insomnia/184/resources/app.asar/node_modules/@getinsomnia/node-libcurl/dist/Easy.js:5:18)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:14)
>
> (insomnia:4925): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:49:38.190: Theme parsing error:
> gtk.css:1413:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
>
> (insomnia:4925): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:49:38.197: Theme parsing error:
> gtk.css:3286:25: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
>
> (insomnia:4925): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:49:38.198: Theme parsing error:
> gtk.css:3748:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
> WARNING: Kernel has no file descriptor comparison support: Operation
> not permitted

Comment: gtk-css seems to be to old for the the system. The css property "font-feature-settings" can't be used in your environment. However: this is a cosmetic bug that will **not** render your app unusable. Your problem is a missing library: `Error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found`. Since this is snap territory I'm not able nor willing to help. It seems that they didn't package it right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is open issue:

https://github.com/Kong/insomnia/issues/5531

I done this:

```
sudo snap remove insomnia
wget https://github.com/Kong/insomnia/releases/download/core%402022.6.0/Insomnia.Core-2022.6.0.snap
sudo snap install Insomnia.Core-2022.6.0.snap --dangerous
```

and insomnia works, but I lost all my collections.

So if you do not have backups and have valuable collections you have 3 options:

- do backup before using this method
- wait when this issue will be closed ( probably soon )
- try downgrade insomnia by command

```
sudo snap revert insomnia
```

Comment: revert worked! thanks